# Postgresql, return all combinations of 1 columns for one key grouped by another column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have one table with an id as a primary key and 2 columns with numerical values.
The first one is the timestamp, the second one is a value. Sample:

```
id    timestamp    value
1     10:22        1306
1     10:55        1100
1     10:56        1130
1     11:44        1000
2     10:18        1100
2     11:19        1105
2     11:21        1106
```

I want to transform it so I output all the possible combination of values for one id, where values are in the same hour and timestamp of the start value is < to timestamp of the stop value. Example of output:

```
id    hour    start_value    stop_value
1     10      1306           1100
1     10      1306           1130
1     10      1100           1130
2     11      1105           1106
```

I try do it with a cross join, however I have to apply this on very large tables and it needs to be computing efficient.

```
select v1.id, date_trunc('hour', timestamp), v1.value, v2.value
from table v1
cross join table v2 on date_trunc('hour', v1.timestamp)=date_trunc('hour', v2.timestamp)
where v1.timestamp<v2.timestamp
```

How can I do that in Postgresql in an efficient way?

Comment: What is `stop_value`?

Comment: this is value with a greater timestamp than start_value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
select v1.id, date_trunc('hour', v1.timestamp), v1.value, v2.value
from t v1 join
     t v2
     on v1.id = v2.id and
        date_trunc('hour', v1.timestamp) = date_trunc('hour', v2.timestamp) and
        v1.timestamp < v2.timestamp
where date_trunc('hour', v1.timestamp) = '10:00'::time;
```

[Here](http://rextester.com/JEFC19412) is a rextester.

Comment: Thank you, that works nearly like a charm :) however if there was other hours than 10 where there is at least one pair it should return them. In my example above it doesn't return 11 because there is no pair, but if there was then it should. Would it work if I transform your where to a group by? I believe the query would crash if one hour has no pair.

Comment: I have edited my samples input/output to reflect that in a concrete way

Comment: removing the condition fixes it